# Show the GridVisibility based on button Command

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid

I have a Grid which should be collapsed by default it is in A xaml file.
Another Button in Grid in another xaml file.When clcik button Grid should be enabled.

How to achieve this I have Tried this can you please help

```
 <Grid Visibility={Binding Visibilityproperty}/>

 <Button Content="A" Command={Binding VisibilityCommand"}/>
```

In button command i have written the logic to enable the visibilityproperty to visible

But grid is not at all visible if i do like this

Better solution in MVVM pattern is welcomed

Comment: You need to show us the code. Enough code for us to reproduce the issue. How can anybody possibly guess what you did wrong?

Comment: could you give me a solution to enable grid based on button in mvvm patter i tried this

Comment: I downvoted you for refusing to show us the code. Do you understand?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<Button Content="Button!">
    <Button.Triggers>
        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Button.Click">
            <BeginStoryboard>
                <Storyboard>
                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.Target="{x:Reference dataGrid}"
                                                   Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility">
                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0"
                                                Value="{x:Static Visibility.Visible}"/>
                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                </Storyboard>
            </BeginStoryboard>
        </EventTrigger>
    </Button.Triggers>
```

{x:Reference dataGrid} references a DataGrid with the name dataGrid, alternatively you could just use Storyboard.TargetName. You would normally use the Storyboard.Target property if you do binding or references to resources.